# In JqGrid Display Date Time../Date(1352658600000)/

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

```
/Date(1352658600000)/
```

When Display the date Date is not Display in Proper Format.

How to convert in to proper `Format(dd/mm/yyyy)`?

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client or the server, and which language  in?

Comment: Asp.Net MVC 3.0 And Client Side....

Answer (score 7):

All you need to make the conversion is setting `date` formatter in jqGrid colum model:

```
$('#gridId').jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel: [
        ...
        { name: 'Column Name', index: 'Column Index', ..., formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y"} },
        ...
    ],
    ...
});
```

For the `newformat` option jqGrid supports [PHP date formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the accepted answer here -  [Converting json results to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date-in-javascipt)

You need to extract the number from the string, and pass it into the Date constructor:

```
var x = [ {"id":1,"start":"\/Date(1238540400000)\/"}, {"id":2,"start":"\/Date(1238626800000)\/"} ];

var myDate = new Date(x[0].start.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1));
```

The parts are:

```
x[0].start                                - get the string from the JSON
x[0].start.match(/\d+/)[0]                - extract the numeric part
x[0].start.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1            - convert it to a numeric type
new Date(x[0].start.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1)) - Create a date object
```