# AngularJS Date Filter with /Date(############) format

Tags: javascript, datetime, angularjs

I have a json object which I can load and parse using AngularJS.
The FirstName and other fields are display as expected.

I need to display the DateLogin which is json shows as `"/Date(1306745196000)/"`

following example at: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

In my code I have

```
<small>login:  {{mem.DateEntered | date:'medium'}}</small>
```

which is rendered as

```
login:  /Date(1306745196000)/
```

expected

```
login:  May 30, 2011 1:46:36 AM
```

How do I I use AngularJS date filter to show a friendly date with json having /Date(##########)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom filter that converts it to a javascript date object and then returns the filtered result.

See: [Converting json results to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date)

And then just use the filter on the resulting object.