# How to convert the string to an new Date

Tags: angularjs

I am using `angularjs`, from the back-end i am getting a date information as a string like this

`/Date(1262293800000+0300)/`

How can convert that details to readable date like example : `04 March 2015` like so?

here is my function :

```
    $scope.conractorInfo = function ( contractor ) {

                $location.search('id', contractor.Id);

                server.contractor.get({id:$routeParams.id, contid:contractor.Id}).$promise.then(function (data) {

                    $scope.contractor = data;

                    console.log(typeof $scope.contractor.WeekDate);
//consoles as : `/Date(1262293800000+0300)/`

                });

            }
```

Comment: Will you answer control.

Comment: if so please accept/vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the format with **angularjs filter** ?  [Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackk88888/7eBWP/26/)

**Html File**

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <span>{{date[0] | date:'mediumDate'}}</span>
</div>
```

**Js File**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
   var regex = /\d+/g;
   var string = "/Date(1262293800000+0300)/";
   $scope.date = string.match(regex);


}
```

Comment: I am updated like this : `<span>{{contractor.WeekDate | date:'medium'}}</span>` but the result in browser is `/Date(1262293800000+0300)/` - like this.

Comment: Oops I got it now. :)

Comment: Try {{contractor.WeekDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}

Comment: I'm not sure if JSON date are parsable by angular filter... http://stackoverflow.com/a/17726610/700209

Answer (score -1):

Even if AngularJs offer filter function for date this can't filter JSON date, standing at documentation:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or [various ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ)

You should convert it to a date, and then use filter, or, if you wish create a custom filter [like this](https://gist.github.com/kwokhou/5873356) (not tested by me, just an idea).

Otherwise I'd suggest to use library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/):

```
moment("/Date(1262293800000+0300)/") //
```

The library also offer some [formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) options to show data as you wish.

*You should use ISO8601 complaint date, this is an old format, if you are in .NET environment take a look at [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serialization library.*