# jquery parseJSON does not work with my json date saying Unexpected token /

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

Thats my json string or part of it: `"/Date(1423232459000)/"`

I do  `var date= $.parseJSON(item.createdAt);`

but an error is thrown in the console:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token /`

How can I fix that or read the date?

Comment: Why the slashes? It's interpreted as a RegEx, and RegExes cannot be parsed in JSON.

Comment: Slashes? Thats the way I get it from the sharepoint server.

Comment: @Pascal,the response is not in a json format.Use regex to get the date string

Comment: What does the actual response back from the server look like?

Comment: @Pascal check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/2776550)

Comment: Actually there's nothing inherently invalid about having that value in a JSON string. it is not "interpreted as a RegEx", it's parsed as a string (it has quotes around it after all). Are you sure this is the code causing the error? Here's your code in JSFiddle not causing any errors: http://jsfiddle.net/nfkwmaox/

Comment: Thanks I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date :-)