# Why +str is a better than str*1 in JS to convert string to number?

Tags: javascript, semantics

Say I have a string, which value is already a number, e.g. `var str = "1234"` Now I want to convert it to number.

I have seen two tricks on the internet so far,

1. Use the unary `+`:  `var num = +str`
2. Use the multiply operator `*`: `var num = str*1`

I want to know which one is better in general.

As I saw from the comment of the accepted answer here: [Converting Json Results to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date), it seems like `*1` is best to be avoided. Is this true and what is the reason behind it?

Comment: For integer, parseInt() would be better

Comment: The unary plus is by definition intended to convert a value to a number, so it's more semantically correct than multiplying by 1 which introduces another operand. @EricSo - parseInt() is better only if you specifically want to ignore any non-numeric data or decimal place value in the string - otherwise it is *worse* than the unary plus *because* it ignores that stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fewer operations, basically.

The unary plus calls the internal `toNumber` method, whereas the multiplication operator calls `toNumber` as well, then does a math operation on it.

Why do the extra steps?

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-mul-operator

Comment: Thanks. Clean & clear answer, and let me know that + is not hacky at all..it is indeed the official intention to do the job

Comment: I wouldn't say it is the 'official intention' as there are strongly typed languages that implement  the unary `+`.  However, when using a specific JavaScript subset called `ASM`, the `+` is officially used to type define a floating point number and `<value> | 0` is used to type define 32bit integers.