# javascript date from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using json to get date from asp.net controller witch get date from ms sql database.

In JavaScript i get object with strange date type

```
Object BloodTestID:23
Date:"/Date(1451599200000)/"
Name:"Hb"
PersonBloodTestID:0
Value:"151"
__proto__:Object
```

How to convert "/Date(1451599200000)/" into 01.01.2016?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDate(str){        
    // extract number from string using regex
    var stringNum = str.match(/\d+/)[0];

    // turn number into int
    var intNum = stringNum * 1;

    // turn int into date
   return new Date(intNum);

var str = '/Date(1451599200000)/';
alert(getDate(str));
```