# Timestamp to UI5

Tags: sapui5

currently, I'm trying to add some date parameter to my add

from my backend I get

> /Date(1525521600000+0000)/

I tried some methods like

```
    <Text text="{path: 'ValueDate',
                type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime',
                formatOptions: {
                style: 'medium'                                                         
                       }
                }"/>
```

But this gives me no Output

If i try

```
<Text text="{path: 'ValueDate',
                type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Date',
                formatOptions: {
                style: 'medium'                                                         
                       }
                }"/>
```

I simply get out

[image]

But I want an Output like dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding:

```
 text="{
        path: 'ValueDate',
        formatter: '.formatter.dateFormatter'
    }"
```

Formatter Function

```
 function dateFormatter (jsonDateString){ 
   return new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get a standard OData Date Object, you have to do this via the formatter function of SAPUI5:

```
text="{
    path: 'ValueDate',
    formatter: '.formatter.date'
}"
```

in the formatter.js file you have to implement a "date" function and convert it to your desired value.
For more information on formatters:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.5/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html

Comment: isn't there a way to do this without using a formatter?

Comment: No, because "/Date(1525521600000+0000)/" is not a standard OData Date or Datetime. For OData it is just a string. Please refer to this: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem

Comment: I have referred to this document I found, but well it doesn't work for me https://www.sap.com/documents/2016/06/98304518-767c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html

Comment: why dont you send it as DateTime or Date from your Backend? would be the easiest imho | and btw. the formatter should also work for a string... ;-) so where's the issue?

Comment: @zYrEx I tried Dats as type from my backend too, but got the same result

Comment: do you have a working formatter on this particular field? paste your function, then I'll add some coding...

Comment: to be honest, I don't really know how to write this particular formatter.

Comment: then you should invest into this, formatter is one of the basic functions, necessary all over ui5 apps .... if you found it out use: function dateFormatter (jsonDateString){     return new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));} and chk out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date

Comment: Formatters: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.5/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html

Comment: @zYrEx Thank you for your advice, I did know how to use a formatter, my problem was, that I didn't know what I had to use in the {} bracket, which you solved for me :)

Comment: ok, glad to help. nicely accept one of the answers and upvote the other one, because both are correct in some way.