# how to convert datetime formate into date in asp.net mvc angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

> i add data into database like this

```
or.Date = DateTime.Now;
            or.Inches = item.Inches;
            or.note = not;
            or.paid = pad;
            or.ProductDes = item.ProductDes;
            or.ProductId = item.Id;
            or.ProductName = item.ProductName;
            or.ProductQty = item.ProductQty;
            or.ProductRate = item.ProductRate;
            or.SaleProduct = item.SaleProduct;
db.orders.Add(or);
db.SaveChanges();
```

> date saved into database this form 08/06/2018 11:18:10
>
> now i get all the data but date formate is not in correct formate [click here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inHYD.png)
>
> this is html code..here try all the angularjs date formate but i get a wrong date formate... my date datatype is datetime in database

```
<tr st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in cca">
                                    <td style="color:black">#{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                    <td style="color:black">{{row.Invoice}}</td>
                                    <td style="color:black">{{row.Date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                                    <td style="color:black">{{row.TotalItem}}</td>
                                    <td style="color:black">{{row.TotalBill}}</td>
                                    <td style="color:black">{{row.remaining}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cateedit(row.Id)">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color:black">
                                                </i>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" ng-show="catehide" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="catedelete(row.Id)">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:white">
                                                </i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

> my angularjs code is

```
function checking() {
    $http.get("/Login/checking").then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.success) {
            $scope.ordersss = response.data.Content;
            $scope.adminsalehistory = "Your Sale History";
        } else {
            $scope.ordersss = response.data.Content;
            $scope.adminsalehistory = "All Sale History";
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can use `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to convert your date into desire format and pass `date in string format` from view page.

Comment: Refer [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: can you try out solution

Comment: @gaurav bhavsar can you write the answer?

Comment: thanks for your response but i face little bit confusion now i shared a angularjs code how i change a date formate.plz see a code

Comment: @Mr.James - dont see you code

Comment: @Mr.James please use `console.log` and check what you are getting in your `Http.Get` response and share yous response, which help us to know exact issue.

Comment: check @StephenMuecke link, its solve your issue.

Comment: thanks developers i solved my issue... by only write this     {{row.Date.slice(6, -2) | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date