# cant extract date '/Date(1617667200000+0000)/'

Tags: php, xero-api

I am using cakephp4 and a Xero API. I can't find the code to convert a date returned as `'/Date(1617667200000+0000)/'` from a Xero API. It is a timestamp with the first 10 digits eg the `$rr=gmdate("Y-m-d", 1617667200);` will work but I can't hardcode strings like this or just find the first 10 digits. It's a StringUtil I believe. I tried using JSON date examples as well but not getting anywhere including Xero docs.

```
 $rr=StringUtil::convertStringToDate($date);//no
 $rr=gmdate("Y-m-d", $date);  //no
```

[Converting json results to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244094/converting-json-results-to-a-date)

Comment: it seems to me like it's generated in milliseconds so timestamp `1617667200000` should be divided by 1000 or just cut last 3 zeros to get it in seconds (which is used in PHP). Check Xero API's documentation for the format they use.

Comment: no i tried this as it not a timestamp as there are too many digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression will extract this with ease:

```
$text = '/Date(1617667200000+0000)/';
preg_match('#^/Date\((\d{10})#', $text, $matches);  // Use # as delimiter.
                                                    // From start match /Date(
                                                    // match and capture next 10 digits

$dt = new DateTime('@'.$matches[1]);                // Create PHP DateTime object from unix timestamp

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // 2021-04-06 00:00:00
```

See https://3v4l.org/5jT5B

Edit - simpler version, no need for a regex if the data format is consistent

```
$text = '/Date(1617667200000+0000)/';
$timeStamp = substr($text, 6,10);
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$timeStamp);                // Create PHP DateTime object from unix timestamp

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    // 2021-04-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: great solution! However in cakephp this code isnt working as the datetime object doesnt exists, there must be a workaround https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/time.html

Comment: this works so its not a big deal,  debug(date('Y-m-d',$matches[1]));   great solution

Comment: DateTime exists in every version of PHP since 5.2. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php If you're on a version that doesn't have it you should be upgrading as a matter of urgency.